# How to debug Eclipse crash on startup?

Tags: java, eclipse

Sometimes I have to deal with an improperly configured Eclipse installation and when I try to run it only the dialog "Java was started but returned exit code shows up without giving me any useful information to trace the actual reason Java failed to start.

What is the best approach to debug this kind of problem?

Comment: Start eclipse from command line

Comment: do you know some special arguments to log the startup? with no args it just return with no info

Comment: tried with both eclipse mars and Spring Tool Suite but I don't see any log

Comment: See my updated answer. You need to edit the ini file first.

Comment: Also see [Where can I find that elusive .log file?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F) on the Eclipse wiki.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [several command-line options](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/runtime-options.html) that can help with troubleshooting. I'd start with `-debug -consoleLog` and see if that produces useful output.

Answer (score 4):

You can run eclipse with the `verbose` attribute from command line

```
eclipse -verbose
```

Read more about debugging eclipse and plugins here http://exploreeclipse.blogspot.nl/2014/01/enable-eclipse-verbose-for-trouble.html?m=1

By default, eclipse launches with javaw.exe process, since it's a window thread so you will not be able to see any verbose messages.

> Step 1:  Add below VM parameter in eclipse.ini file. By default, eclipse will have javaw.exe, modify it to java.exe
>   -vm
>   C:/KK/jdk1.6.0_32/bin/java.exe
>
> Step 2: Pass verbose parameter during the eclipse launch.
>   eclipse -verbose