# jvm terminated. exit code 1 eclipse linux

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Peace be upon you :)

Basically I am trying to install Eclipse in linux (Debian 8 (Jessie)).

I Downloaded the package from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/1a/eclipse-java-neon-1a-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz

As Explained here: https://linuxconfig.org/install-the-latest-eclipse-java-ide-on-debian-8-and-ubuntu-16-04-linux

Extracted it. But then when I run the eclipse I get the error saying:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=1
/usr/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
...
```

I Tried Inputting: `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.cairoGraphics=false`
In my eclispse.ini file But didn't worked.

I also Tried: `update-alternatives --config java` which the output is:

```
* 0 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 1071 auto mode
  1 /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java            1    manual mode
  2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java 1071 manual mode
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: There's probably not enough information to help you. Also see [How to debug Eclipse crash on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33569849/608639) on Stack Overflow and [Where can I find that elusive .log file?](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_can_I_find_that_elusive_.log_file%3F) on the Eclipse wiki.

Comment: The message is stating the problem: you need to use java 8. It seems that you have it installed, but it is not selected (the index 1). Try selecting it and run the instalation again.

Comment: OMG, I Don't know why But I had it tried before couple of times But didn't worked then. Now As you Said @luizfzs I selected index 1 and it worked